# What are the difference between double backslash and single slash in reg for .?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Two commands below :

```
grep ', \\.' enrolments


grep ', \.' enrolments
```

got the same result as shown below

```
COMP4001|4368523|Doddau Yobhazravi, .             |8684  |M

COMP9315|4368523|Doddau Yobhazravi, .             |8684  |M

COMP9321|4368523|Doddau Yobhazravi, .             |8684  |M

COMP9331|4368523|Doddau Yobhazravi, .             |8684  |M

COMP3121|4896558|Vozaila, .                       |3978/3|F

COMP9321|4896558|Vozaila, .                       |3978/3|F

COMP9031|4389601|Yiehil, .                        |8680/2|M

COMP9318|4389601|Yiehil, .                        |8680/2|M
```

What are the difference between double backslash and single slash in reg for .?

Comment: You haven't demonstrated the double  backslash int he question.

Comment: Can you confirm that you used `grep ', \.'` enrolments rather than `grep ", \."` enrolments? I can only reproduce with the double quotes.

Comment: @rici : same here.. Also the op might share some light about his environment.

Comment: @sjsam: If they were double quotes, the behaviour would be expected on any compliant shell.

Comment: double backslash would escape the last one rather than the dot, but single backslash escapes the dot.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect that you actually used double quotes rather than single quotes in your shell command.

In shell, `", \."` and `", \\."` are *exactly the same string*. They are also the same as `', \.'`. But `', \\.'` is different.

In a double-quoted string, only a few characters can be escaped using a backslash. Any other use of the backslash is considered a normal character. Since `.` is not one of the characters (they are <kbd>$</kbd> <kbd>`</kbd> <kbd>\</kbd> <kbd>"</kbd> and the newline character), the <kbd>\</kbd> in `\.` is not considered special. On the other hand, the first <kbd>\</kbd> in `\\` is treated as an escape character, so it escapes the second <kbd>\</kbd>. Either way, you end up with <kbd>\</kbd> <kbd>.</kbd>.

In a single-quoted string, the backslash character is *never* treated as special. It is always treated as just an ordinary character.

Consequently:

```
$ echo "\." "\\." '\.' '\\.'
\. \. \. \\.
```

So if you used double quotes, the two commands

```
grep ", \\." enrolments

grep ", \." enrolments
```

actually do exactly the same thing, and that has nothing to do with `grep`. In both cases, the pattern passed to grep is `, \.`. `grep` then interprets the backslash character as making the <kbd>.</kbd> an ordinary pattern character rather than a wildcard.

However, `grep ', \\.' enrolments` would pass the pattern `, \\.` to `grep`, which will be interpreted as searching for the sequence <kbd>,</kbd> <kbd>SP</kbd> <kbd>\</kbd> followed by any character. That won't be matched by any of the sample lines you present, since none of them contain a literal backslash.