# cat `-q` file (in linux) - passing operands that look like options

Tags: linux, bash, arguments, command-line-arguments, operands

I have a file whose name is `-q` (It looks like this is made by accident)

I want to see it’s content, so I tried these

```
$ cat '-q'
$ cat "-q"
$ cat $'-q'
```

But nothing worked.(All gives same error `cat: invalid option -- 'q'`)

Is there any way to see it’s content?

Comment: The quotes are, in every single case, removed by the shell *before* the `cat` executable is started. Thus, it has no idea what quotes (if any at all) were used. They control how the shell parses content, and thus how the shell breaks a string into an argument list -- but for every single quoting form given here, the syscall invoked is exactly the same: `execv("/usr/bin/cat", {"cat", "-q", NUL})`, or an equivalent thereto.

Comment: `cat ./-q`, btw, would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to create a file named `-q` do

```
touch -- "-q"
```

and to view its contents

```
cat -- '-q' # Used single quotes to treat anything inside as literal characters
```

should do it. `--` means what follows should be treated as a positional parameter.

---

<sup>Pls take time to look at @rici's [[ answer ]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38627556/1620779) which reminds some substle aspects regarding single vs double quotes.</sup>

Comment: Funny enough, this doesn't work. I tried it on my system and got `> cat: \-q: No such file or directory`.

Comment: Same result. Maybe `cat ./-q`?

Comment: `cat -- "-q"` worked. Anyway `--` was a key! Thank you.
(`cat -- "\-q"` didn’t worked for me too.)

Comment: `touch "\-q"`, at least on my system, creates a file named `\-q`.

Comment: @SebastianLenartowicz : Forget my last comment. It should be `touch -- "-q"`

Comment: @sjsam How about to add my result(`cat -- "-q"`) to your answer? Then I can check your answer as a solution.

Comment: @plhn `cat -- "\-q"` would do the same thing though as the escape character `\`  will be neglected. But not needed here anyway

Comment: `cat -- -q` would be fine too. The quotes are removed by the shell here, they have no impact on what's passed to `cat`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : Yes, but i put double quotes to accommodate nonstandard files- say some that contains spaces - and so. Single quotes could be used too..

Answer (score 5):

[sjsam's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38690386/45375) offers viable solutions, but it's worth **digging deeper**:

Arguments passed to Unix utilities (such as `cat`) can be divided into two groups (using POSIX terminology):

- **options** (e.g., `-l`; depending on the option's definition, possibly followed by an *option-argument*) - switches that *modify the utility's basic behavior*.
- **operands** (e.g., a filename) - the *data that the utility operates on*.

[POSIX requires all options, if any, to come *before* any operands](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html), but *GNU* utilities relax this requirement to allow intermingling options and operands for convenience.

Either way, a `-` followed by a letter or digit generally implies an *option*.

So as to allow passing *operands* that *happen to* start with `-`, **special option `--` can be used to tell any utility: treat any subsequent arguments as *operands***, even if they *look* like options.

---

Since operand `-q` in this case *looks* like an option, preceding it with `--` to mark it as an *operand* is a must.

As for how to pass string `-q` itself as an argument:

- `-q` contains *no* shell *metacharacters*, so the shell passes it *as-is* to `cat` - no quoting needed.
- Quoting (`'-q'`, `"-q"`, `$'-q'`, `\-q`) *does no harm in this case*, but has absolutely *no effect* here, because the shell - after having applied any expansions - simply *removes* any quoting characters (a process called [quote removal](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quote-Removal.html#Quote-Removal)) before passing the word to `cat` (as [Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy) notes in comments on the question).